# checking whether or not a video is picture in picture mode

Tags: javascript

I want a way to check whether or not a video is in picture in picture mode after someone has entered in picture in picture mode. They may close the video in PIP mode by clicking the X button,I want to check the state of the video with a recursive function and see when they close it, and change the class of some element.
something like this

```
if(video.isInPipMode){
someRecursiveFunction();
}
```

is there anyway , any property to check the state of a video and see whether or not it is still in PIP mode, thanks in advance/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either check the document for the `pictureInPictureElement` to see if there is a current video in PiP mode. It either returns the element that is currently in PiP mode or `null` when there is not.

```
if (document.pictureInPictureElement !== null) {
  someRecursiveFunction();
}
```

Or attach events to the video to listen for when a video enters or leaves the PiP mode.

```
let pipActive = false;

video.addEventListener('enterpictureinpicture', () => {
  pipActive = true;
});

video.addEventListener('leavepictureinpicture', () => {
  pipActive = false;
});
```